# Como calcular a porcentagem da CPU?

Tags: linux, porcentagem

No *linux*, quando se abre o *monitor de sistema*, e no *windows*, quando se abre o *gerenciador de tarefas*, temos uma porcentagem de CPU. Como se chega a esse código? Como chegar a esse cálculo utilizando as chamadas do *linux*?

Answer (score 1):

Vou tentar responder essa pergunta com uma analogia.

Imagine que você tem que ir da sua casa até a praia de taxi, e você está disputando esse taxi com outras pessoas que também querem ir para a praia. Só há um taxi em toda cidade, e o taxista sabendo disso diz o seguinte:

- Posso te levar a praia, mas você só pode andar 10 minutos de cada vez no meu taxi. A cada 10 minutos eu largo você aonde estivermos e pego outra pessoa para levar para a praia. Assim que a fila de pessoas acabar, eu pego você onde eu deixei e te levo por mais 10 minutos.

E assim ele vai fazendo até levar todos até a praia.

Bom, alguem pode perguntar: Como eu calculo a porcentagem de uso do taxi de uma determinada pessoa indo para a praia?

Depende. Se considerarmos que ou a pessoa anda de taxi ou fica parada, as porcentagens instantâneas serão sempre 100% ou 0% respectivamente. Mas se você pegar um slot de tempo, podemos calcular uma *média*.

Por exemplo, você dispara o cronômetro quando entra no taxi, e assim que sai você para o cronômetro. Na média dos últimos 10 minutos o uso do taxi foi de 100% (considerando que você não pediu para sair do taxi e nem o taxista te mandou descer antes dos 10 minutos). Você pode pegar um slot um pouco maior, digamos de 20 minutos, então levando em consideração que você andou de taxi nos primeiros 10 minutos e foi largado na rua depois disso para que o taxista pegasse outro passageiro, então você andou 50% do tempo (dos 20 minutos) de taxi.

É assim que é calculada a porcentagem de uso de CPU dos processos que aparecem no TOP. É simplesmente a razão entre o tempo de uso da CPU (tempo dentro do taxi) e o tempo total de um slot pré-determinado de tempo (tempo do cronômetro).

É claro que a entrada e saída de processos da CPU é mais complexa do que simplesmente um cronômetro contando uma fatia de tempo. Há prioridade, entrada/saida, interrupções de hardware, software... Depende também do tipo de escalonador, mas a porcentagem de uso da CPU de um processo é calculada a partir de uma fatia pre determinada de tempo.

Vou dar um chute aqui: Calcule a cada 2 segundos (tempo que o top atualiza a lista) e veja os resultados que consegue.

ps: caso não tenha ficado claro, o taxi é o processador e os passageiros os processos.

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748136/how-is-cpu-usage-calculated

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular eu imagino que ele verifica qual a quantidade de dados que estão sendo processados pela capacidade do processador.

Para recuperar as informações (do top) para exibir, da pra fazer da seguinte forma: 
https://superuser.com/questions/602759/how-to-get-cpu-percentage-and-memory-usage-on-single-line

Espero que isso consiga resolver o seu problema.

Comment: O top não vai se aplicar aqui porque eu queria fazer isso em C. Mas valeu mesmo assim.

Answer (score 0):

Se você não fizer questão do uso *instantâneo* do processador, você pode ler o `/proc/loadavg`: ele é um arquivo de uma linha (que você pode ler normalmente com `fopen`, `fscanf`, etc.), no formato

```
0.78 0.62 0.60 1/349 5082
```

Os três primeiros números são a média de uso ao longo dos primeiros um, cinco e dez minutos; o quarto grupo diz quantos processos estão ativamente rodando/quantos processos no total estão carregados, e o último número é o PID do último processo que usou a CPU.

(Note que essa média de uso pode ser maior do que um, mas o “máximo” dela é o número de processadores da máquina, que você pode descobrir lendo `/proc/cpuinfo`. Se a média for maior que o número de processadores, isso indica que a máquina está a 100% e ainda assim não está conseguindo dar conta do serviço.)

Comment: Eu queria fazer isso relacionado a um processo específico. Para isso eu estava usando C e calculando o que eu queria. Só que o processamento é mais difícil de achar e de calcular porque eu não sei exatamente esse cálculo.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber como se calcula o % de uso de CPU que que lembrar os conceitos de binário e valvulas.
O processador ou está em uso =1 ou esta parado, aguardando =0.
Num intervalo de tempo calcula-se a quantidade que ele está ligado e divide-se pelo total possível.